# Multiply and Add Functions

Tags: optimization, gpu, opencl, fma

This question is regarding the mad functions available in OpenCL which promise significant improvements for calculations of the type:

```
a * b + c
```

if used as `mad(a,b,c)` and compiled with cl-mad-enable.

I have tried a calculation of the form `a + b * c + d * e` using mad for a very huge size and was expecting significant improvement. Surprisingly, it took the same time.

If anybody has experience of this, I would appreciate some insight. I have a jist that it should work because most of the resources are full of praise for `mad()`. Note: The data types I am using are all doubles, and if it is important, my usage of `mad` resulted in a v. huge precision loss.

Comment: Does your GPU actually support doubles? A lot of them only support float.

Comment: Not by default, but by enabling cl_khr_fp64, I can work with them. You may have a point, I will convert to float and check. Since the code is very large, it will take some time. I will comment back once I have something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's a big difference between being able to handle doubles, and being able to handle double precision efficiently.  Most recent GPUs handle double, but are circa 2X-4X slower than single precision.

   However, AFAIK all of the GPUs that handle double have madd instructions.  AMD documents this - e.g. see [R600-Family ISA](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/r600isa.pdf), dated 2008, the MULADD_64 instruction.  I've seen less detailed documentation for Nvidia, but docs like [Floating Point for NVIDIA GPUs](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/Floating_Point_on_NVIDIA_GPU_White_Paper.pdf) say Nvidia has FMA (Fused Multiply Add). The manuals for Intel GPUs at https://www.x.org/docs/intel/ don't mention double precision (at least not to google).
2. However, probably the main reason you are seeing no difference when using madd(), is that the compiler is already recognizing that a madd can be used.

   On some GPUs you can look at the code generated; e.g. AMD CodeAnalyst or AMD [GPU ShaderAnalyzer](https://gpuopen.com/archive/gpu-shaderanalyzer/) for OpenGL code.

   I have spent a lot of time looking at code generated with these tools, and IIRC it was optimized.  TBD: show an example here.

Comment: In C and C++ the compiler isn't allowed to convert `a*b + c` into an FMA operation because that'll produce a different result. The user must explicitly call `madd`

Comment: @phuclv It's more complicated than that. See standard macro `FP_CONTRACT`.